# error in enabling hyper-v

Tags: windows-phone-8, hyper-v

i have installed window 8 pro. but still unable to run my window phone 8 application. and also i have already enabled hyper-v from my window features settings.
it showing error "hypervisior is not running". and also i have enabled virtulization from my bios settings.
what should i do now . 
see the snapshot of my error
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By99iBtpMUurLVU2cVNXSHJ3dUE/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By99iBtpMUurVTNqWW9fN2xTNWs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

As I've answered on another forum - try running Hyper-V Manager directly and try starting the emulator image manually. Most likely there is some error in question unrelated to Windows Phone 8 development.